# Создание меток за 300 баллов репы

Tags: поддержка, метки, создание-метки

[За 300 баллов можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) создавать свои метки, однако не написано где кнопка "создать метку".
Внимание вопрос : Где кнопка?

Comment: А такая кнопка должна быть? Может быть все  просто, если набрать в списке меток вопроса новую метку, то она добавится?

Comment: @avp принял, сработало, это не было очевидно. Теперь надо вручную зайти отредактировать метку и добавить описание. Спаисбо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нет кнопки. Просто у вопроса пишешь нужную метку и она создаётся.

Метки не существуют, когда с ними нет вопросов. Да и при одном вопросе существуют недолго.

Чтобы добавить созданной метке описание и/или краткое описание, надо перейти на неё.

Answer (score 1):

По упомянутой вами [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) на справку процедура создания метки уже описана:

> [image: скриншот справки]

> **Как создать новую метку?**
>
> Просто добавьте нужную метку к вашему вопросу – и она создастся.
> Создавая новую метку, помните, что она должна:
>
> - быть короче 25 символов;
> - состоять только из А-Я A-Z 0-9 + # -.

Comment: знаки `+` и `#` добавили только ради `c++` и `c#`? :)

Comment: @Danis не только. Там много всего интересного может быть, если на enSO глянуть. На ruSO добавили только кириллицу. А вообще, в справке надо поправить длину и точку опробелить.